# How to reposen 405 of TRACE response in elixir ( Phoenix Framework )

Tags: api, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to handle the any TRACE method api call to 405 status code, "Unhandle Method" with a response body. Now it is behave like elixir default behaviour is itself by return 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED. I already tried adding plug that handle and response the 405 status code but when I call the api from postman with the TRACE method its not even reach to my api code.

Comment: Without you showing your attempt, we would not be able to help.